# Async function with 2 awaits needs to pause and redirect after both await functions are consumed

Tags: javascript, forms, axios, fetch

I am using a form and then the data is being sent to 2 database.. one using a third part external API (evento) which I am accessing from my internal API (/api/v1/eticket/visitor) and one to my own mongo database using an internal API (/api/v1/users/updateMe)

Here's the code on the frontend that triggers on `submit` of the form

```
// UPDATE SETTINGS
const saveSettings = document.querySelector(".form-user-data");

if (saveSettings) {
  saveSettings.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    const lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    const mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const company = document.getElementById("company").value;
    const profile = document.getElementById("profile").value;
    const country = document.getElementById("country").value;
    const nationality = document.getElementById("nationality").value;
    const type = document.getElementById("type").value;
    const visitorId = document.getElementById("visitorId").value;

    const visitorForEvento = {
      VisitorNumber: visitorId,
      FirstName: firstName,
      LastName: lastName,
      Mobile: mobile,
      Email: email,
      Company: company,
      JobTitle: profile,
      Country: country,
      Nationality: nationality,
      Category: type,
    };

    // UPDATE EVENTO DATABASE
    await updateEvento(visitorForEvento, "evento");

    // UPDATE MONGODB
    await updateSettings(
      {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        mobile,
        email,
        company,
        profile,
        // address,
        // city,
        country,
        nationality,
        type,
      },
      "data"
    );

    alert(
      "This function should halt here and pause and then redirect to another view"
    );
  });
}
```

And here's the 2 functions that update their own databases. I wanted to be consistent and use only `fetch` for both but for some reason it wouldn't work with fetch but worked with `axios`.. and that's the reason I am using 2 different request methods below...

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
import axios from "axios";

export const updateEvento = async function(data, type) {
  try {
    const url = "/api/v1/eticket/visitor";

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    const res = await response.json();

    if (res.status === "success") {
      console.log(`${type.toUpperCase()} Updated`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.response.data.message);
  }
};

export const updateSettings = async function(data, type) {
  try {
    const url =
      type === "password"
        ? "/api/v1/users/updateMyPassword"
        : "/api/v1/users/updateMe";

    const res = await axios({
      method: "PATCH",
      url,
      data,
    });

    if (res.data.status === "success") {
      console.log(`${type.toUpperCase()} Updated`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

Now in the function assigned to 'saveSettings' for `submit` the there are 3 things happening..

updateEvento()
updateMongo()

and then I want the flow to pause here and redirect to another page on success...

However I have added an alert function but for some reason the function keeps moving ahead and doesn't stop there.. The other 2 functions are completing successfully .. the data is being udpated.. however I am not able to pause anywhere and specially at the end of both functions completing successfully I'd like to pause and redirect. But I can't seem to do this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pause waiting for what? Or for how long?

Comment: Basically I would like to have this code  `window.setTimeout(() => location.assign("/"), 3000);` after the `alert` but for now I am not able to even show the `alert`

Comment: Honestly everything looks fine to me. Id try console.log instead of alert, some browsers just block them so maybe thats the issue.

Comment: Changed the `alert` to `console.log` but still no change.. there is a `console.log' in 2 other functions `updateEvento` and `updateSettings` but the function seems to just show the first one in `updateEvento` and disapper and the one from `updateSettings` doesn't even appear and the last one in the function assigned to the `submit` event too doesn't show

Comment: is it possible that the e.preventdefault() is not working? Anyways to check this?

Comment: Could be. If document.querySelector(".form-user-data") is of type button, try to change it to input with type="button" so it wont auto submit.

Comment: @RaniSharim Thanks for your help.. I found out my mistake.. I've updated my answer more as a reminder to myself never to make this mistake again!

Answer (score 0):

I realised my mistake and in case anybody else faces the same issue, please double check the action applied to your button!

I had assigned a function on submit to the form. And the button had a class of 'update-data' .. but I will be careful next time to have such a generic name for a button.. I had in some other form, a similarly named button, and had applied a function for a 'click' event and this function was kicking in when I was submitting my form.

I lost 2 days of my life.. I hope this will help someone else to save those.